# ¿Cómo aplico :hover a un elemento padre y que afecte a un elemento hijo?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un objeto padre al que quiero aplicar un :Hover para modificar su posición, pero a la vez, un elemento hijo que tiene opacidad 0 me gustaría aplicarle opacidad 100%.

Os dejo el código

Este es el CSS

```
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;    
}

nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}

.icon {
    color: rgb(107, 107, 107);
    font-size: 3em;
    display: block;
}

.text {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: rgb(107, 107, 107);
    opacity: 0;
}

.menuObj {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Y este es el HTML:

```
        <li class="menuObj">
            <a href="#">
                <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                <span class="text">Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

EDIT: Lo que quiero conseguir es lo siguiente:

```
.menuObj:hover .text{
top: 0;
opacity: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
.menuObj:hover .text {
    /*Este estilo aplica al hijo solo cuando el padre tiene el estado :hover*/
    opacity: 100%;
}
```

Edit: Cambié las clases para adaptarlo a este caso particular

Comment: Gracias por responder Fedex, en este caso al aplicar el :hover > .text no aplica el hover a .menuObj

No entiendo por qué :S

EDIT: No es es que no se aplique el hover, si se aplica, pero solo aplica la opacidad, no me mueve el top: 0;